# Array list (CardView) with same layout but different data

Tags: arraylist, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, parcelable

Edited Post: 21 April 2020

So I am getting a NullPointerException when I am now trying to call my description onto my new Customer Activity. I can't seem to call my description from my ArrayList to the new Activity TextView. I might have missed out on something.

MuaActivity (MainActivity),

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import Adapters.MuaAdapter;
import CustomerActivities.Customer1Activity;

public class MuaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private MuaAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mua_list);

        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Make Up Artists");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        final ArrayList<MuaView> muaView = new ArrayList<>();
        muaView.add(new MuaView(R.drawable.mua_image, "Shima Matin Bridal Services", "Shima Matin started in 2012"));

        // ArrayList

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_list);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mAdapter = new MuaAdapter(muaView);

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Item Click listener for CardView and Parcel CardView to new Intent

        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MuaAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MuaActivity.this, Customer1Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("Customer's Details", muaView.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        });

    }

    // Filter/Search Bar

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();

        searchView.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
}
```

MuaAdapter,

```
import android.com.example.weddingappfinale.MuaView;
import android.com.example.weddingappfinale.R;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MuaAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MuaAdapter.MuaViewHolder> implements Filterable {

    private ArrayList<MuaView> mMuaView;
    private ArrayList<MuaView> mMuaViewFull;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public static class MuaViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageButton mImageButton;
        public TextView mTextView1;
        public TextView mDescription;

        public MuaViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, final OnItemClickListener listener) {
            super(itemView);
            mImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mua_imageButton);
            mTextView1 = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mua_title);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            mImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (listener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                            listener.onItemClick(position);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public MuaAdapter(ArrayList<MuaView> muaView) {
       mMuaView = muaView;
       mMuaViewFull = new ArrayList<>(muaView);
    }

    @Override
    public MuaViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.mua_view, parent, false);
        MuaViewHolder mvh = new MuaViewHolder(v, mListener);
        return mvh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MuaViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MuaView currentView = mMuaView.get(position);

        holder.mImageButton.setImageResource(currentView.getImageResource());
        holder.mTextView1.setText(currentView.getText1());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMuaView.size();
    }

    public Filter getFilter() {
        return MuaFilter;
    }

    private Filter MuaFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            List<MuaView> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                filteredList.addAll(mMuaViewFull);
            } else {
                String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

                for (MuaView item : mMuaViewFull) {
                    if (item.getText1().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredList.add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            results.values = filteredList;

            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mMuaView.clear();
            mMuaView.addAll((ArrayList) results.values);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    };
}
```

ModelClass MuaView,

```
    package android.com.example.weddingappfinale;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class MuaView implements Parcelable {
    private int mImageResource;
    private String mText1;
    private String mDescription;
    private String mServices1;
    private String mServices2;
    private String mContact;
    private String mAddress;

    public MuaView(int imageResource, String text1, String description) {
        mImageResource = imageResource;
        mText1 = text1;
        mDescription = description;

    }

    protected MuaView(Parcel in) {
        mImageResource = in.readInt();
        mText1 = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<MuaView> CREATOR = new Creator<MuaView>() {
        @Override
        public MuaView createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new MuaView(in);
        }

        @Override
        public MuaView[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MuaView[size];
        }
    };

    public MuaView(int mua_image, String shima_matin_bridal_services, int catering_title) {
    }

    public int getImageResource() {
        return mImageResource;
    }

    public String getText1() {
        return mText1;
    }

    public void setmDescription(String mDescription) {
        this.mDescription = mDescription;
    }

    public String getmDescription() {
        return mDescription;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(mImageResource);
        dest.writeString(mText1);
    }
}
```

activity_customer.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/image_customer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title_customer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/image_customer"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_semibold"
            android:text="" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description:"
            android:layout_below="@id/title_customer"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_extrabold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionVendor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Description of Vendors"
            android:layout_below="@id/description"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/services"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/descriptionVendor"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_extrabold"
            android:text="@string/services" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/services1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/services"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/services"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/services"
            android:text="Services1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/services2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/services1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/services"
            android:text="Services2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/gallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/services2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_extrabold"
            android:text="@string/gallery" />

        <com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider
            android:id="@+id/imageslider"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/gallery"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_margin="4dp"
            app:delay="0"
            app:placeholder="@drawable/mua_image" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contact"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageslider"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_extrabold"
            android:text="Contact:"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/contactVendor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/contact"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="ContactVendor" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/address"
            android:layout_below="@id/contactVendor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Address:"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_extrabold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/addressvendor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/address"
            android:text="AddressVendor"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

CustomerActivity,

```
 package CustomerActivities;

import android.com.example.weddingappfinale.MuaView;
import android.com.example.weddingappfinale.R;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.denzcoskun.imageslider.ImageSlider;
import com.denzcoskun.imageslider.models.SlideModel;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Customer1Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_customer1_mua);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        MuaView muaView = intent.getParcelableExtra("Customer's Details");

        int imageRes = muaView.getImageResource();
        String line1 = muaView.getText1();
        String description = muaView.getmDescription();

        ImageButton imageButton = findViewById(R.id.image_customer);
        imageButton.setImageResource(imageRes);

        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.descriptionVendor);
        textView.setText(description);

        TextView textView1 = findViewById(R.id.title_customer);
        textView1.setText(line1);

        ImageSlider imageSlider = findViewById(R.id.imageslider);
        List<SlideModel> slideModels = new ArrayList<>();
        slideModels.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.catering_image));
        slideModels.add(new SlideModel(R.drawable.entertainment_image));
        imageSlider.setImageList(slideModels, true);


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a database to pass data into model class and load in rcyclerview through adapter class.
For that, you must have a recyclerview or cardview layout first. I recommend recyclerview as cardview is old approach... then You have to store all your data inside an arraylist.
just for example I am showing you string type data list:

List yourListName = new ArrayList<>;
Then loop your data and pass it to arraylist like this.

yourListName.add(your data here);

and pass it to adapter class constructor, in which you have added arraylist parameter. 
for loading data you need model class, adapter class and from that activity you'll pass the arraylist where you want to show your data.
and arraylist we pass in adapter class constructor as I said.

I am checking the code I'll add another answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding. I already have an adapter for my cardview and recyclerview. Currently, all my layouts are the same with parcelable. However, I would like to change the text of some of the textviews. Where do I store all these data? I will edit my question to include my java and xml files.

Comment: Will you please add some more lines what do you want from that code. How you want to show the data or just you need to pass the data from drawable and strings.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your response. I have added the context in it so you have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

The data you pass from **Customer1Activity** needs a model class Like:

```
public class SlideModel{

int Imagepath;

public SlideModel(int Imagepath)
{
   this.Imagepath = Imagepath;

}

 public int getImagepath() {
        return Imagepath;
    }

    public void setImagepath(int Imagepath) {
        this.Imagepath = Imagepath;
    }

}
```

and where in **MuaActivity** you needs a model class like:

```
public class MuaView{

  private   int pic;
  private   String text;

    public RecipeModel(int pic, String text) {
        this.pic = pic;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getPic() {
        return pic;
    }

    public void setPic(int pic) {
        this.pic = pic;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

**and made these changes to your adapter:**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MuaViewHolder holder, int position) {
    MuaView currentView = mMuaView.get(position);

    holder.mImageButton.setImageResource(currentView.getPic());
    holder.mTextView1.setText(currentView.getText());
}
```

You did not pasted your model class. and what's the layout name, try the above code hope it helps otherwise I'll add code samples for passing data into recyclerview if you need.

Comment: Hi sir, I am having trouble on where this should be added. Apologies but can I get code samples for it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Kamran, I have tried your code but it is not what I would like to achieve. I have already achieved sending the data from my cardview to my new intent through parcelable. However, I would like to add more data to respective new intents as now, all intents shows the same textviews.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type

Comment: Hi Kamran, i've understood what you wrote sir. For long descriptions, where do you store the data? Or do I need a database?

Comment: You can use database or it not to pass data into recyclerView, You can pass the data from a Database or static data(images from drawable and text inside double quotes).

Comment: As you can see I am passing data in public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity from drawable there I stored images with name c, cc, ccc etc.

Comment: Understood. What if I had a long text description? Like details on history etc.

Comment: Yes. But where do I store that and how? In an activity?

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Hi Kamran, sorry it took awhile. Been busy with stuffs lately. I have added as was said but I am getting null exception. I can't seem to call my "Description". I'm going to edit my whole post and hope I can get your 2 cents. Thanks.

Comment: The layout name is activity_customer1_mua.xml sir.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=12qDswojOl3o8K3106atJpz8NPF6uKo_X here is the link sir. Apologies to trouble you

Comment: I run your app, there is no exception, you havn't code for contact, subscribe and feedback(fragments) yet and there is gridView with photo and descriptino when you click on View it takes you to another activitym where you are showing that image and text to the user.

Comment: It is running smoothly, what do you want further.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212184/discussion-between-kamran-khan-and-rahimaris).

Answer (score 0):

If the answer is not helping you I would like to add a simple code that may give you some hints.

**Xml Main File where my recyclerView lies:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:listitem="@layout/sample_recyclerview"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Xml layout I made for loading data into:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="165dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/download"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:background="@color/pinkish"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:shadowColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is my model class for data to load:**

```
public class RecipeModel {

  private   int pic;
  private   String text;

    public RecipeModel(int pic, String text) {
        this.pic = pic;
        this.text = text;
    }

    public int getPic() {
        return pic;
    }

    public void setPic(int pic) {
        this.pic = pic;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

**And here is the adapter class shows how to load data from model class and load into your made layout inside Oncreate method of adapter:**

```
public class RecipeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecipeAdapter.viewHolder> {

    ArrayList<RecipeModel>  List;
    Context context;

    public RecipeAdapter(ArrayList<RecipeModel> list, Context context) {
        List = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sample_recyclerview, parent, false);
        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, int position) {
        RecipeModel model = List.get(position);

        holder.imageView.setImageResource(model.getPic());
        holder.textView.setText(model.getText());

        holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Item is clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return List.size();
    }

    public class viewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
        public viewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        }
    }
}
```

**and here you pass the values from the activity where you created recyclerview tag:**
and I've commented different style of recyclerView you can use it to see difference.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycleView);

        ArrayList<RecipeModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.add(new RecipeModel(R.drawable.cc, "A Picture"));
        list.add(new RecipeModel(R.drawable.ccccc, "A Picture"));
        list.add(new RecipeModel(R.drawable.ddd, "A Picture"));
        list.add(new RecipeModel(R.drawable.download, "A Picture"));
        list.add(new RecipeModel(R.drawable.flower2, "A Picture"));
        list.add(new RecipeModel(R.drawable.images, "A Picture"));
        list.add(new RecipeModel(R.drawable.littlegirl, "A Picture"));
        list.add(new RecipeModel(R.drawable.pler4, "A Picture"));
        list.add(new RecipeModel(R.drawable.plw, "A Picture"));
        list.add(new RecipeModel(R.drawable.qwe, "A Picture"));
        list.add(new RecipeModel(R.drawable.port, "A Picture"));
        list.add(new RecipeModel(R.drawable.rg5fs, "A Picture"));

        RecipeAdapter adapter = new RecipeAdapter(list, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

//        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
//        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

//        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, true);
//        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

//        GridLayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this, 3);
//        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        StaggeredGridLayoutManager staggered = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(staggered);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Kamran, I still don't really know where do I pass the data so it is shown on the layout. I have edited the post to show you what I mean.

Comment: You passing values in MuaActivity and in Customer1Activity, where you add values to the lists.